# After server migration website is loading too slow

Tags: centos7, migration

I am migrating a Magento website to a new server. I have followed all the basic steps involved in migration. But now after doing everything my website is loading too slow on the browser.
URL: http://www.getpaper.shoppingmegamart.com/

I basically have an Unmanaged VPS server.
Server details: OS - centOS7, Hard disk - 100GB (out of this only 5 GB is used), RAM - 5GB.

Also when I try to test my website speed through Gtmetrix I get a read timeout error. . Screenshots[image]

When I test my website for security scan details from magento secutity scan I get an error related to "Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received".[image]

This is my first time configuring a server. I also have firewallD installed and running.
I feel I might be missing some configurations due to which Gtmetrix and magento security scan are not able to scan my website. Also why my website is loading so slow in the browser. Could anyone help me or guide me anywhere as I am really stuck and not able to understand how to proceed.

Comment: Are you sure you installed all the same software as the server before had? Especially caching software.

Comment: my OS is centOS 7 and installed software based on this, my website is running perfectly on the frontend but is slow. I feel it could be because of RAM. I think 5 GB is less but I could not understand why Gtmetrix is not able to scan my website.

Comment: You still need to make sure you have the same software stack running as you had in the older server. If you don't have same caching software installed, site still probably works but it is slower.